# Scale divs to equal height, max-height needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

I'm in the process of building a responsive calendar for a site I'm working on. The calendar scales down fine using the following javascript to keep the divs set to the same height.

```
    $(function(){
    var equalHeight = function() {
        $(".calBody").each(function(){
            var maxHeight = 0;
            $(this).children(".calBlock")
                .each(function() { maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height()); })
                .css('min-height',maxHeight);
        });
    }

    equalHeight();

    $(window).resize(function(){equalHeight()});
});
```

This keeps the columns nice and even from the start and as it gets scaled down, however when you start scaling back up it keeps the max height of the divs from when they were at their tallest.

Any ideas on getting them to scale to be only as tall as whats needed for the tallest div scaling both up and down?

Here is a jsfiddle of it in action: [jsfiddle.net/7n4VH/1](http://jsfiddle.net/7n4VH/1)

Comment: Can you show some markup as well? Even better would be a jsFiddle

Comment: Here's the best I could do as it's dynamically generated and don't want to modify a bunch of code to add spaces and tabs: http://jsfiddle.net/7n4VH/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting the .height() of the children of .calBlock instead. Something like:

```
.each(function() { maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).children('.events:first').height()); })
.css('min-height',maxHeight+30);
```